# How can I get the last line of a .csv file with python3?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm writing a little script in python for taking the last added line to a .csv file, process it and write it in a data.txt file but when I try to reverse the csv reader it gives me an error. (`csv reader not subscriptable` and `reverse list not subscriptable`)

I have Tried things like

```
raw_data = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=",")[::-1]
```

and

```
reversed(list(csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=",")))
```

But none of these works,

Here's the piece of code

```py
with open("data-2019-09.csv", "rt") as csvFile:
    raw_data = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=",")[::-1]
    data = [
        raw_data[0][0],
        raw_data[0][7],
    ]
    self._file_object.write(data)
```

The thing I want to do is like this

```
open "data-2019-09.csv" as csvFile:
    take the last line and store it in raw_data
    data = [
        take the first variable in raw_data,
        take the eighth variable in raw_data,
    ]
    print data
```

But I don't understand how to take the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want just want to get the last line of the given csv, I would suggest to use `numpy.loadtxt`

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('example.csv', delimiter=',')
```

the above code will give you the csv file in the form of a 2d array.

Comment: it gives me an error (`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'`) because in the table there are some missing values and I want that if it's `None` it gives me None not anything else :D